# VBA code to open multiple selected hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba

I need to open multiple links in selected cells at once. Only the selection part of the code below work. when clicked on OKAY, nothing happened/ none of the hyperlinks were opened in the browser.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

      'Update 20141124
        Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink
        Dim WorkRng As Range
        On Error Resume Next
        xTitleId = "Openlinks"
       Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
        Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, 
  Type:=8)
        For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
            xHyperlink.Follow
        Next
       End Sub
```

Comment: please attach your file

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin Note that files cannot be attached. Stack Overflow does not support this because all the necessary things needed to ask a proper question need to be in the question itself (see [mcve]). Also no one here would download a file (that is able to run code) from an unknown source. [Ask] and [help] might provide further information too.

Comment: @TZhang You must remove `On Error Resume Next` this line hides all your error messages but they still occur. You just cannot see the messages. If you don't see the messages you cannot fix the errors. Remove that line and see if you get any errors and fix them. You cannot debug a code that has just `On Error Resume Next` (without a full proper error handling).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I removed "On Error Resume Next" and run the subroutine again ... I didn't get an error but the hyperlinks were not activated either

Comment: Then there are no hyperlinks in that range. Your code works fine. Make sure you really added real hyperlinks. If you only put the URL in the cells it does not work. This code needs real hyperlinks. See [Work with hyperlinks in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/work-with-hyperlinks-in-excel-7fc80d8d-68f9-482f-ab01-584c44d72b3e)

Comment: @P EH, Yes, you're right. I have the formula "=LEFT(F7,58)&TRIM(A7)&RIGHT(F7,1)" in Cell "A1", then formula "Hyperlink("A1","Website Link") in Cell "B1", and When I selected "B1", the code is not working unless I manually copied the URL(as a text not a formula). Is there an automated way to convert the formula to text in "A1"?

Comment: It seems that the code only works on the cell where the hyperlink is inserted from the "Insert link" on the ribbon, and do not work on the cells where the hyperlink was inserted using the "Hyperlink" formula ... Can anybody please help?